# How to conclude from here that $f$ is a constant function or not?

Tags: complex-analysis

let $f:\mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb C$ be an analytic function with the property that $|f(z)| \in \mathbb Z \forall z\in \mathbb C$. How to conclude from here that $f$ is a constant function or not?

Comment: Clearly $f$ misses any point on the circle $|z|=\pi$ so...

Comment: Have you heard of the open mapping theorem yet?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $z\mapsto |f(z)|$ is continuous and so its image must be connected.

Comment: Can I ask u a bit more.I have some doubts on another problem.Are u ok with that

Comment: @learnmore, ask a separate question.

Comment: Ok I will  do that