# How to conclude from here that $f$ is a constant function or not?

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an extension of a  previous problem I had asked before

$f:\mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb C$ be analytic with the property that $f
(z)=i$ when $z=1+\frac{k}{n}+i \forall k \in \mathbb N$.how to conclude that $f$ is constant from here?$n \in \mathbb N$

Comment: What's with the dangling $n$?

Comment: Do you know something called the identity theorem?

Comment: Previous question at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1038492/.

Comment: Are $k$ and $n$ arbitrary in $\mathbb N$ ?

Comment: yes @lhf they are arb.